# RemoteNotification TOKEN not received if push notifications are not allowed

Tags: air, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

Really confused with this one!

I have an Adobe AIR iOS app and I am using the RemoteNotifier to subscribe for PushNotifications. More details http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ios-push-notifications.html

I have the following listeners.

```
remoteNotifier.addEventListener(RemoteNotificationEvent.TOKEN, onToken);
```

After I reset my iPod to factory settings and reinstall my app (using the adhoc distribution), I click *"Don't allow"* for the pushnotifications when I get prompted.

I find that I then don't receive any **RemoteNotificationEvent.TOKEN**, so my app basically hangs waiting for that.

If I go to my **Settings**, **Notifications** and have a play with

- Toggle Alert Style from the **None** to **Alerts** AND
- Then back to **None** again (as it was)

I find that I can go back and launch my app with not problems. It's just that on the very first time user flow, I don't seem to get any **TOKEN** back.

Any ideas? Has anybody else seen this behaviour?
Or knows how I should handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I am correct, someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

From what I am able to find out, you won't get a **RemoteNotificationEvent.TOKEN** when the user clicks on *"Don't Allow"*.

For some reasons that I am still unclear about, how after you play with the Settings and relaunch the app, you get the **RemoteNotificationEvent.TOKEN**, regardless of the notification settings you have set. But maybe that's the way it's meant to be?

So, really I have to change the flow such that I don't wait on that **RemoteNotificationEvent.TOKEN** before loading my first screen. If the **TOKEN** comes back, it comes back, otherwise if it doesn't, it's not a big deal as that means the user clicked on *"Don't allow"* and we don't need to send PUSH notifications anyway.

Everytime I relaunch my app, I do make the call to subscribe and get the **TOKEN** though, such that if the user was to enable the Notifications in the phone's Settings, I do have a TOKEN ID to send the push notification too.

The only problem I see with this though, is that should the user change the Notification to ON via the phone Settings and doesn't relaunch the app (to retrieve the **TOKEN**) then the device doesn't get push notifications.

Not sure how to handle this?